Recyclerview state problem when fragment navigation for result
I have a recyclerview with a list of settings. And on click I navigate to a settings detail fragment which gets some details about the settings change. After changing the setting it pass the result and return to the list
Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigateUp()

The problem is that the settings list is recreated and the scroll bar position is lost.
I tried to use save and restore layoutManager state, like
activityViewModel.recyclerViewState = binding.settingsList.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()

'''
settingsList.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(activityViewModel.recyclerViewState)


But it didn't work. Maybe it's because it's called before the adapter elements with the view holders are created (How do I know that everything I need has already been created?)
What is the correct way to call a fragment when navigating with a jetpack to get the result, back and restore the recyclerview state?
